# How to show popover after dismissing keyboard

Tags: ios

_momVC = [[MOMViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MOMViewController" bundle:nil];
    _momVC.contents =  decodedString;
    _momVC.delegate = self;
    _momVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 90);

```
popoverControllerfornote = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_momVC];
popoverControllerfornote.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 80.0);
//popoverControllerfornote.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight || UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[popoverControllerfornote presentPopoverFromRect:[btn frame]
                                          inView:pagebar
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES];
```

Comment: _momVC is an instance of a view controller

Comment: when I pressed Keyboard  popover displays but when I dismiss the keyboard  this popover dismisses which I don't want

Comment: If you touch/tap outside the popover it will be dismissed.

Comment: Actually I want the popover should not be missed after hide/dismissing the keyboard

Comment: i.e when I dismissed keyboard popover is also dismissing which I don't want , popup should be visible after dismissing  keyboard